# Multi-threading a for statement with php

Tags: php, multithreading

I'm using this following function to check if images exist at their location. Each time the script runs it load about 40 - 50 urls and so its taking long time to load the page. I was thinking of using threading for the "for statement" (at the end of the script) but couldn't find many examples on how to do that. I'm not very familiar with multi-threading with php but i found an example here using popen.

My script:

```
function get_image_dim($sURL) {

  try {
    $hSock = @ fopen($sURL, 'rb');
    if ($hSock) {
      while(!feof($hSock)) {
        $vData = fread($hSock, 300);
        break;
      }
      fclose($hSock);
      if (strpos(' ' . $vData, 'JFIF')>0) {
        $vData = substr($vData, 0, 300);
        $asResult = unpack('H*',$vData);        
        $sBytes = $asResult[1];
        $width = 0;
        $height = 0;
        $hex_width = '';
        $hex_height = '';
        if (strstr($sBytes, 'ffc2')) {
          $hex_height = substr($sBytes, strpos($sBytes, 'ffc2') + 10, 4);
          $hex_width = substr($sBytes, strpos($sBytes, 'ffc2') + 14, 4);
        } else {
          $hex_height = substr($sBytes, strpos($sBytes, 'ffc0') + 10, 4);
          $hex_width = substr($sBytes, strpos($sBytes, 'ffc0') + 14, 4);
        }
        $width = hexdec($hex_width);
        $height = hexdec($hex_height);
        return array('width' => $width, 'height' => $height);
      } elseif (strpos(' ' . $vData, 'GIF')>0) {
        $vData = substr($vData, 0, 300);
        $asResult = unpack('h*',$vData);
        $sBytes = $asResult[1];
        $sBytesH = substr($sBytes, 16, 4);
        $height = hexdec(strrev($sBytesH));
        $sBytesW = substr($sBytes, 12, 4);
        $width = hexdec(strrev($sBytesW));
        return array('width' => $width, 'height' => $height);
      } elseif (strpos(' ' . $vData, 'PNG')>0) {
        $vDataH = substr($vData, 22, 4);
        $asResult = unpack('n',$vDataH);
        $height = $asResult[1];        
        $vDataW = substr($vData, 18, 4);
        $asResult = unpack('n',$vDataW);
        $width = $asResult[1];        
        return array('width' => $width, 'height' => $height);
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {}
  return FALSE;
}

for($y=0;$y<= ($image_count-1);$y++){
$dim = get_image_dim($images[$y]);
    if (empty($dim)) {
    echo $images[$y];
    unset($images[$y]);
    }
}
$images = array_values($images);
```

The popen example i found was:

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    // open ten processes
    for ($j=0; $j<10; $j++) {
        $pipe[$j] = popen('script.php', 'w');
    }

    // wait for them to finish
    for ($j=0; $j<10; ++$j) {
        pclose($pipe[$j]);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which part of my code has to go in the script.php? I tried moving the whole script but that didn't work?

Any ideas on how can i implement this or if there is a better way to multi thread it? Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to look at using the curl library and its async facilities. http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/

Comment: if you want threads, consider the pthreads extension. if you just want to do async http requests, consider curl_multi or http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#async-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not have multi-threading natively.  You can do it with `pthreads`, but having a little experience there, I can say with assurance that that is too much for your needs.

Your best bet will be to use `curl`, you can initiate multiple requests with `curl_multi_init`.  Based off the [example](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) on PHP.net, the following may work for your needs:

```
function curl_multi_callback(Array $urls, $callback, $cache_dir = NULL, $age = 600) {
    $return = array();

    $conn = array();

    $max_age = time()-intval($age);

    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    if(is_dir($cache_dir)) {
        foreach($urls as $i => $url) {
            $cache_path = $cache_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.sha1($url).'.ser';
            if(file_exists($cache_path)) {
                $stat = stat($cache_path);
                if($stat['atime'] > $max_age) {
                    $return[$i] = unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_path));
                    unset($urls[$i]);
                } else {
                    unlink($cache_path);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
        $conn[$i] = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $conn[$i]);
    }

    do {
        $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        // Keep attempting to get info so long as we get info
        while (($info = curl_multi_info_read($mh)) !== FALSE) {
            // We received information from Multi
            if (false !== $info) {
                //  The connection was successful
                $handle = $info['handle'];
                // Find the index of the connection in `conn`
                $i = array_search($handle, $conn);
                if($info['result'] === CURLE_OK) {
                    // If we found an index and that index is set in the `urls` array
                    if(false !== $i && isset($urls[$i])) {
                        $content = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);
                        $return[$i] = $data = array(
                            'url'     => $urls[$i],
                            'content' => $content,
                            'parsed'  => call_user_func($callback, $content, $urls[$i]),
                        );
                        if(is_dir($cache_dir)) {
                            file_put_contents($cache_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.sha1($urls[$i]).'.ser', serialize($data));
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle failures how you will
                }
                // Close, even if a failure
                curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $handle);
                unset($conn[$i]);
            }
        }
    } while ($status === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $active);


    // Cleanup and resolve any remaining connections (unlikely)
    if(!empty($conn)) {
        foreach ($conn as $i => $handle) {
            if(isset($urls[$i])) {
                $content = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);
                $return[$i] = $data = array(
                    'url'     => $urls[$i],
                    'content' => $content,
                    'parsed'  => call_user_func($callback, $content, $urls[$i]),
                );
                if(is_dir($cache_dir)) {
                    file_put_contents($cache_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.sha1($urls[$i]).'.ser', serialize($data));
                }
            }
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $handle);
            unset($conn[$i]);
        }
    }

    curl_multi_close($mh);

    return $return;
}

$return = curl_multi_callback($urls, function($data, $url) {
    echo "got $url\n";
    return array('some stuff');
}, '/tmp', 30);

//print_r($return);
/*
$url_dims = array(
    'url'     => 'http://www......',
    'content' => raw content
    'parsed'  => return of get_image_dim
)
*/
```

Just restructure your original function `get_image_dim` to consume the raw data and output whatever you are looking for.

This is not a complete function, there may be errors, or idiosyncrasies you need to resolve, but it should serve as a good starting point.

Updated to include caching.  This changed a test I was running on 18 URLS from 1 second, to .007 seconds (with cache hits).

*Note:* you may want to not cache the full request contents, as I did, and just cache the url and the parsed data.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get it to work with my original function but managed to edit it to get similar values that i can use.

Comment: Another thing to note: You may want to consider caching the results to load the page significantly faster (and lower your bandwidth usage).  I will add an example above.